# redirect to action result on Ajax.BeginForm Post to MVC controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ajax.beginform

I am creating a form with Razor syntax. I have different partial views inside one page(one header and different tabs with their own save button). I am using Ajax.BeginForm() to submit the form. So my problem here is when I save the header the post controller is not redirecting to the get header action(getting 401 unauthorized error). I know this is because of the ajax post instead of regular html form post. So how can I solve the 401 error and redirect to Header get after save.

**Create.cshtml**

```
    @{Html.RenderAction("Header", "controller", new {id = Model.id});}

   --additional tabs
```

**_Header.cshtml**

```
@using(Ajax.BeginForm())
   { Submit button}
```

**controller:**

```
public ActionResult Create(int? id){
    return view("Create", id);
}

--Header get
public ActionResult Header(int? id){
     --get Header info
     return PartialView("_Header", model);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Header(HeaderModel model){
     --save header
     return RedirectToAction("Header", new {id = model.id})
}
```

Comment: return the url and redirect via js

Comment: So i should use the Jquery to update the div instead of Ajax.beginForm doing the update work? currently I am updating the div from the ajaxOptions

Comment: register the onsuccess js callback and you can send a flag plus url and decide if redirect is required pick the url and redirect via js

Comment: the RedirectToAction simply returns the URL of the action method to which the user is being redirected. It does this by setting the response code to 302, and including a "Location" header in the HTTP response which contains the URL. The is telling the caller where to go to get the real content. If you use a regular (non-ajax) postback, the browser will pick up the redirect header automatically and make a new request to the suggested URL. Ajax calls do not do this - you would have to write some JS yourself to read the header and follow it.

Comment: But...the whole point of ajax is to avoid redirects, postbacks, excessive calls to the server etc. And also it should not be trying to receive the content of an entire view in its response - only a partial view (to be injected into the current page), or some JSON data to make use of should be expected. So it seems you have a bit of a contradiction in your design. Decide if you're using a regular approach or an ajax one,and design accordingly.

Comment: However if you're getting a 401, this suggests you're not even getting as far as the first action, never mind the redirected one - the redirect is not the cause of your 401 problems (like I said, a redirect would return 302). Sounds like you need to make sure your code supplies the correct auth data with the ajax request.

Comment: The whole point of ajax is to stay on the same page. If you want to redirect, do not use ajax - make a normal form submit

Comment: Actually, I am not trying to redirect the page. I wrote one Action for Get and one for Post. On page load, I am using the Get Action. Once I did the Ajax Post Need to get the new saved Header right? So, I am trying to redirect to get method. Currently What I am doing is I wrote a separate method for GetHeader and calling that in both Get and Post Actions. So that I don't have to redirect.